OT concerning customer relationship?
Does anybody have contact details for tradebot.bid?
I refrained from asking anything remotely like a customer service question and instead asked if anybody has contact details so that I can take my customer service question to the appropriate channels. How can this possibly be OT?

I agree that it probably shouldn't have been closed as off topic. People can just get a little trigger happy with that closure reason once one person reports it :) I've reopened it, if anyone disagrees with it being reopened we can discuss it here 
